# Can a pixie shift under a medium creature's legs?

Tags: dnd-4e, pixie

What are the rules for occupying the same square as an enemy while tiny? There are provisions to occupy the same square for allies, and a feat that enhances it (here) and a 11th level pixie feat that alludes to movement into enemy spaces ([here](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3657)):

> Flitting Harrier
>   Prerequisite: 11th level, pixie
>   Benefit: When you enter or leave an enemy’s space, you do not provoke an opportunity attack from that enemy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tiny creatures can enter any larger creature's space.**

Rules Compendium p201 (not in DDI, that I could see):

> **Tiny**: Four individual Tiny creatures can fit in a square, and a Tiny creature can enter a larger creature's space and end its turn there.

Incidentally, the definition of adjacent includes creatures in the same square as you so a Tiny creature leaving your square would normally generate an Opportunity Attack.